# How can I use the section parameter to iterate over each document that's inside of a collection to access the count of a subcollection?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

So I'm working on my first workout tracking app and this is my first time using Firebase/Firestore, so I'm just trying to figure out if there is a simple query that I can use for this...

Here is what my Firestore Database structure looks like:

```
/Users/mi9P3TrLwkQ3oDIut/Days/WZ3Q6LDuu1kja/Workouts/BpLGFREoJNzNQW/Exercises/5vRWuHlcJHc/WeightReps/cKrB0Dpf0myEDQV0
```

Basically I need to return a value for numberOfRowsInSection, but the value that I need to access is the number of workouts that are associated with each day of the week, and I'm not too sure how to go about using the section parameter to iterate over each day document in my Days collection in order to access the Workouts subcollections and get the count of the documents there for each day collection. Does that make sense?

I hope that the question makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I am getting your question right but if you want to retrieve several documents with all their attributes this is how you can do it:

```
    var counter = 0

    func getData() {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid


    for data in self.dataSourceArray {
         db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("yourCollectionName").document(data.name).collection("yourCollectionName").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    self.counter += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what youre looking for ?

Comment: Not quite. I'm trying to access and return this value... 

days?[section].workout.count

  But I'm not sure how to get the count of all the documents in a subcollection while iterating through it's parent collection's documents. Does that make sense?

Comment: I dont really understand your Firebase-Structure so I just made a guess. You have to change that accordingly

Comment: Sorry if it's hard to understand, but I'm not actually looking for the count field's value, I'm just trying to get the total count of the documents in each "Workouts" Section for each "Day" section document in order to return a value for the TableView method numberOfRowsInSection. Does that make more sense?

Comment: oh ok, so why don't you just make a `counter` and inside `for document in querySnapshot!.documents`  increment the counter